# What's the best way to create and authenticate users in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

I'm building an app in React and I want users to be able to create an account that I would like to be stored in a mongoDB.

I have done some investigating and there seems to be a ton of strategies and possible implementations on user authentication. Which strategy is the best combination of easy to implement, secure and overall the most optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Spring security. Just create an authenticator project using Spring security. Can use oauth2